# Mysql Error while selecting row

Tags: mysql, sql

I got an error while trying to get a row from `meta` table

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE 'meta';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meta` (
  `key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `key_UNIQUE` (`key` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

mysql> SELECT * FROM 'meta';
+---------------------+-------------+
| key                 | value       |
+---------------------+-------------+
| website_title       | title       |
| website_description | description |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

and now when I execute this `SQL` query `SELECT value FROM 'meta' WHERE key='website_title';` I got an error.

```
mysql> SELECT value FROM `meta` WHERE key='website_title';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ...the right syntax to use near 'key='website_title'' at line 1
```

Comment: Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting such as (avg, at, etc) Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”:  such as ("FROM", "KEY"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a [reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) word (think `primary key`, `foreign key`).  It is best to choose a different name, but if you use it, then use backticks:

```
SELECT value
FROM `meta`
WHERE `key` = 'website_title';
```

A better approach is to change the name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meta` (
    meta_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY.
    meta_value LONGTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Building a unique index on a primary key is redundant.  Don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL. Change the column name.

Reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).